# How to get the value of a BooleanParameterValue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get the value of one of my boolean parameters to build a job.
For example :

```
build job: 'test', parameters:  [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'Param1', value: Param1]]
```

Param1 is a boolean parameter.
The BooleanParameterValue class takes only boolean for the parameter: value.

```
public BooleanParameterValue(String name,
                         boolean value,
                         String description)
```

I've tried the .getValue() function but it didn't worked.
I know that if I put true or false directly in, it works, but it needs to be a variable.
Thx.

Comment: what error does it get in the cases that you've tried? what does it say when you print Param1 (what really is that thing)? maybe you can show the code where you initialize Param1?

Comment: The error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate and Param1 is a boolean parameter in the Jenkins's interface. So it is initialized when I press Build with Parameters. If I print Param1, it prints true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`params` is a global object which holds job build parameters. Also it conserves their types (which is `String` or `Boolean` in most cases).

It is possible to "omit" `params` by referencing straight to boolean parameter by its name, as you have done. But that variable is actually type of String. Assume there is 'aBooleanParameter' boolean parameter set up in job configurations:

```
echo aBooleanParameter.getClass().toString()        // class java.lang.String
echo params.aBooleanParameter.getClass().toString() // class java.lang.Boolean
```

So, more orthodox way to give parameter is to your build would be

```
build job: 'test', parameters:  [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'Param1', value: params.Param1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the toBoolean() function !

```
build job: 'test', parameters:  [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'Param1', value: Param1.toBoolean()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Travenin answer,
you could also pass your

```
def object_type(param_key, param_value){
      switch(param_value.getClass()) {
        case java.lang.Boolean:
          return [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: param_key, value: param_value]
          break
        case java.lang.String:
          return [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: param_key, value: param_value]
          break
    }
}

def job_parameters = []
job_parameters.add(object_type("Param1", params["Param1"]))

build job: 'test', parameters: job_parameters
```